# What is Disk space limit format (Giga byte, Kilo Byte, etc.) in Google Cloud repository?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, repository

I don't know why someone forgot to add the disk space format.
How do I set the limit now not knowing is it a Mega byte or Giga byte or even bytes...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The quota unit is bytes. For example, the example quota is 214 GB.